# Inconsistent solutions when computing the stationary distribution for small Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, stationary-processes

I have a small discrete Markov chain with the following transition matrix:

$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1-r & r
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\
r & 1-r & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This should be ergodic, since the whole Markov chain is a single recurrent class. However, when I try to solve for the stationary distribution $\pi$ in two ways, I get inconsistent solutions.

Since $\pi^{\top} = \pi^{\top} P$ by definition, one way to brute force approximate the stationary distribution is just to raise $P$ to a high power.

```
r = 1/7
P = np.array([
    [0, 0  , 1-r, r],
    [0, 0  , 0, 1],
    [1, 0  , 0, 0],
    [r, 1-r, 0, 0]
])
assert np.allclose(P.sum(axis=1), 1)

Pn = np.linalg.matrix_power(P, 1000)
pi = Pn[0, :]
assert np.isclose(pi.sum(), 1)
print(pi.squeeze())
print(np.dot(pi, P).squeeze())
```

This prints something that is clearly not the stationary distribution, since $\pi^{\top} \neq \pi^{\top} P$:

```
[0.53846154 0.46153846 0.         0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.46153846 0.53846154]
```

However, if I solve the system of linear equations, I get a different (also non-stationary) answer:

```
A = np.array([
    [-1 , 0  , 1-r, r  ],
    [0  , -1 , 0  , 1  ],
    [1  , 0  , -1 , 0  ],
    [r  , 1-r, 0  , -1 ],
    [1  , 1  , 1  , 1  ]
])
b  = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1])[:, None]
pi = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)[0]
pi = pi.reshape(1, -1)
assert np.isclose(pi.sum(), 1)

print(pi.squeeze())
print(np.dot(pi, P).squeeze())
```

Here, this prints

```
[0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25]
[0.28571429 0.21428571 0.21428571 0.28571429]
```

What am I doing wrong when trying to solve for $\pi$?

Comment: The transition matrix is periodic, since from states $\{1,2\}$ you always end up in states $\{3,4\}$ after one step and vice versa. Thus the transition matrix is not irreducible, and so the finite state chain is not ergodic. You can see this by inspecting all the rows of the matrix `P2 = P@P = np.linalg.matrix_power(P, 2)`; the 3rd and 4th row will be your `np.dot(pi, P)`.

Comment: The matrix is irreducible and hence there is a single stationary distribution.  The DTMC is 2-periodic and so the limiting probabilities do not tend to anything, the odd times tend to one thing and the even times tend to another, the average of which is the stationary distribution.

Comment: @Michael, your comment made me realize I have conflated ergodicity with a single stationary distribution. Ergodicity really means that the stationary distribution is the limiting distribution, but a MC that is not ergodic (such as mine above) can still have a stationary distribution. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What are the possible values of $r?$ For example, if $r = 1/2,$ then the chain has two subclasses.

Comment: I see nothing special about $r=1/2$, the system is irreducible whenever $0<r<1$.  It looks like your linear algebra is accidentally solving $(P-I)\vec{\pi}=0$ (which gives solution $\vec{\pi}=(1/4; 1/4;1/4;1/4)$)  instead of $\vec{\pi}^{\top}(P-I)=0$ which for $r=1/7$ gives $$\vec{\pi}=(0.269230769230769;
   0.230769230769231;
   0.230769230769231;
   0.269230769230769)$$

Comment: And yes, every finite state irreducible DTMC has one and only one stationary distribution, that is, a mass function that satisfies $\vec{\pi}^{\top} = \vec{\pi}^{\top}P$. If the DTMC is also aperiodic, then limiting probabilities converge to this stationary mass function.